Tailwind CSS responsive classes / state classes not working
I'm using transform translate-y-value transtion. What I want is for these classes to activate using 'focus' on screens smaller than 'lg' and 'hover' on screens 'lg' or larger.
The idea was to tackle the lack of hover on mobile devices using clicks (and hence the use of focus). Would be grateful if you guys have other ideas to deal with it.
Have a look at the classes in the folllowing tags figure and figcaption for the use of focus and hover.
<div class="max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg">

    <figure class="relative w-full transform transition duration-300 focus:scale-105 lg:hover:scale-105 overflow-hidden group">

...................... Some Image ....................

        <figcaption class="absolute w-full px-6 py-2 pt-6 rounded-b-lg text-white bottom-0 transform translate-y-36 transition duration-300 group-focus:translate-y-0 lg:group-hover:translate-y-0">

................. Headings and paragraphs and stuff ..........................

            </figcaption>
    </figure>  
</div>

Now it works perfectly for screens "lg" and larger but not for focus on screens smaller than 'lg'

Only a limited set of elements can receive focus by default; figure and figcaption don't belong to those. To make elements that aren't focusable by default able to receive focus, you need to specify a tabindex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Only a limited set of elements can receive focus by default; figure and figcaption don't belong to those.
To make elements that aren't focusable by default able to receive focus, you need to specify a tabindex.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex
